# Agregar informação que está por linha numa coluna no excel

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Bom dia

O meu objetivo é conseguir transpor em vba essas 2 linhas para (neste caso 6 linhas)

Ou seja, o que eu quero é repetir a informação toda mas depois quero só ter uma coluna de privilégios mesmo que tenha repetida todo o resto da informação

[image: Imagem do caso]

```
Dim countprivilegios As Integer
Dim linha As Integer
Dim colunaprivilegio As Integer
Dim folhaorigem As String
Dim folhadestino As String
Dim userlinha As String
Dim nomelinha As String

folhaorigem = "Extração Enterprise User InaAct"
folhadestino = "Extração Enter UsersInaActiv"
linhafolhaorigem = 2
colunaprivilegio = 18
userlinha = ""
nomelinha = ""

Do While linha <> ""

    Do While colunaprivilegio <> ""

        '(o que devo colocar aqui)
        imprimir folhaorigem, folhadestino, linhafolhaorigem
        colunaprivilegio = colunaprivilegio + 1
    Loop

    linha = linha + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Não achei muito clara a pergunta, veja [ask]. E crie um [mcve] com os dados da resposta do que deseja com aqueles dados. Também leia [como aceitar respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)

Answer (score 0):

Como o danieltakeshi mencionou acima, se faz necessario mais informações para uma resposta mais acertiva. Mas segue um codigo que fiz que pode ajudar para com o que você precisa:

```
Sub TrasporRangeSelection()

Dim vShtFonte As Worksheet
Dim vShtDestino As Worksheet
Dim vFonteLinhaInicio As Long
Dim vFonteColunaInicio As Long
Dim vFonteColunaFim As Long
Dim vFonteColunaPivo As Long
Dim vFonteRange As Range
Dim vResultSet As Variant
Dim i As Long

    Set vShtFonte = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fonte")
    Set vShtDestino = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Destino")
    vFonteLinhaInicio = 2
    'ColunaPivo neste caso é uma coluna que vai sempre estar preenchido. nunca vai estar em branco qdo a linha estiver preenchida
    vFonteColunaPivo = 1
    vFonteColunaInicio = 5
    vFonteColunaFim = 10
    i = 0

    Do While vShtFonte.Cells(vFonteLinhaInicio, vFonteColunaPivo).Offset(i, 0).Value <> vbNullString

        Set vFonteRange = _
        vShtFonte.Range(vShtFonte.Cells(vFonteLinhaInicio + i, vFonteColunaInicio), _
                        vShtFonte.Cells(vFonteLinhaInicio + i, vFonteColunaFim))

        vResultSet = Application.Transpose(vFonteRange)

        If vShtDestino.Cells(2, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
            vShtDestino.Range(vShtDestino.Cells(2, 1), vShtDestino.Cells(2 + UBound(vResultSet, 1) - 1, 1)).Value = vResultSet
        Else
            vShtDestino.Range(vShtDestino.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0), vShtDestino.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(UBound(vResultSet, 1), 0)).Value = vResultSet
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```